# How to manipulate array in a function

Tags: php, arrays, function

Below is my array which is generating dynamically, meaning it is not defined how many elements will be in this array and the array indexes are not consecutive:

```
$arrayVar = Array
  (
      [0] => hello
      [2] => rahul ku
      [4] => Juhi Chawla
      [6] => Dhak Dhak
      [8] => Best of
      [10] => Jacqueline Fernandez
      [12] => Alia bhatt
  )
```

I want to get result something like this:

```
  Array
  (
      [0] => hello
      [2] => rahul+ku
      [4] => Juhi+Chawla
      [6] => Dhak+Dhak
      [8] => Best+of
      [10] => Jacqueline+Fernandez
      [12] => Alia+bhatt
  )
```

I am doing this in the following way:

```
function rename($value, $key) {
  $name[] = str_replace(' ', '+', $value);
  return $name
}

$getArray[] = array_walk( $fp_title_arr, "rename" );
```

What is the problem? Can I get a nice solution to do this?

Comment: `str_replace()` also takes **arrays** as arguments! JUST DO: `$array = str_replace(" ", "+", $array);`

Comment: @Rizier123 Think , if we have to add something in the all array value, then how can i do that ...

Comment: [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk) is weird.  The array value is passed to your `rename` function as a *reference*.  You need to do this: `function rename(&$value, $key) { $value = str_replace(' ', '+', $value); }`.

Comment: @Rizier123 can we return that all manipulated string in an array.

Comment: @rahul I don't quite get what you are talking about. You have an array in your question and not a string.

Answer (score 6):

`str_replace()` works with arrays:

```
$result_arr = str_replace(' ', '+', $fp_title_arr);
```

**subject**

> The string or array being searched and replaced on, otherwise known as
>   the haystack.
>
> If subject is an array, then the search and replace is performed with
>   every entry of subject, and the return value is an array as well.

**Return Values**

> This function returns a string or an array with the replaced values.

If you are encoding for a URL then you could just do:

```
$result_arr = array_map('urlencode', $fp_title_arr);
```